# How debug the launch of a .desktop Desktop's file

Tags: xfce, .desktop

When I right click a desktop icon, and click 'Execute' after a certain amount of seconds I get:

"Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include:
the remote application did not send a reply,
the message bus security policy blocked the reply,
the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken."

This happens for every icon.
If in a file manager, thunar in particular, I right-click and execute the same
.desktop file, the programs immediately start.
My system is Debian Unstable, xfce, and I work as root
(I knows this is a very bad behaviour, but I do it since 1995 :-)
How can I debug the whole process of launching a .desktop file?
(apart from using strace that I tried but got too much information)

After some testing as a normal user, launching from desktop works, so
maybe the right question is what is the security policy applied (by my system)

Comment: Try to ask here : https://forum.xfce.org/index.php

Comment: have you check on xfce4-mime-settings what the default application is for .desktop files? And what other options do you get (as the default, especially) when you right click a .desktop file? if you found a solution, please do share it here. Otherwise maybe resseting xfce4-mime-settings to default action for that particular type of file maybe fixes the problem.